# How to show a collectionView like this using swift 4?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewflowlayout

[image]Hello i want to show multiple images in `collectionView` just like the above image. i can show two rows and three columns with the help of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, but unable to do that. help is much appreciated.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {        
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0,1:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 4) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 4) / 2)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 6) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
        }

    }
```

Comment: hello @kuldeep Sir, can you please help me regarding this matter..

Comment: fixed height sir

Comment: sir actually i have a arrayof images. if my array has contain 3 images then i want to show this collectionview layout.ok. then i can call another cell if arrayofimages has 3 images.

Comment: only two kind of views, if arrayimages is 3 then this type of view else facebooktype view sir

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: okay sir will do that

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: yes that problem was solved, today i have another question

Comment: sir how to call didDeselectRowAt indexPath? normally it is not calling

Comment: i have a textfield and tableView.. on click textfield the autocomplete process is starting. suppose i click on a cell and then deselect a cell,after that when i click on texfield the cell is showing selected data..which i dnt want.

Comment: Okay sir. but how to handle that thing so that the deselect data will not show on cell

Comment: sir are you busy?

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there? i have a query.

Comment: sir one of my friend face a problem that in his app there is one google login and push notification. google is providing two info p list for google login and push notification. now in a app we can't use two plist. so how to handle this issue sir

Comment: Okay sir thank u lot.

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: how to build a comment section like instagram in my app?

Comment: and if my comment section is image also then i have to add image view also right sir?

Comment: okay sir Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: @Kuldeep sir the plist problem has been solved. Thanks a lot sir

Comment: @Kuldeep sir how to make a comment section like instagram "comments" screen in my app?

Comment: Sorry to bother you sir. please do not mind.

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: how to send a image file to server? i am using Just for post the data. Then i took a variable like  var editProfile_image_path = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "temp.jpg" then in the post file i wrote Just.post(Constant.url.imageadd, params: params,files: ["product_image": .url(URL(fileURLWithPath: editProfile_image_path), nil)]) and then in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo i wrote  do {
                    try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.8)!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath:self.editProfile_image_path), options: .atomicWrite)
                } catch let error as NSError {
              }

Comment: but the image data is not coming.can you help me regarding this matter sir

Comment: okay sir.doing it accordingly

Comment: posted it sir, with the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673775/how-to-send-a-image-file-to-server-using-in-post-function-using-swift-4

Comment: i have post it sir

Comment: @Kuldeep sir yesterday's problem has been solved sir

Comment: sir are you there?

Comment: it's okay.i am facing problem in uploading multiple image to the server.that's why pinged.almost solved it sir. Thank you

Comment: sir are you there?

Comment: okay sir checking.. i have almost solved the multiple image problem, but stuck in another issue

Comment: so i tried to save the imageArray to user defaults, but when ever i tried to save the image array it is getting crashed and showing "Attempt to set a non-property-list object", if you dn't mind can you help me regarding this matter

Comment: which option will i prefer? NSNotificationCenter or user defaults?

Comment: "once you got images from tabbar VC than pass that array with notification" - pass that array means from cameraVC to tab bar?

Comment: Ah Sir you r just genius. solved the problem..thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: ignore it sir, i have solved it

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: Sorry for being late sir, i was absent last three. and the problem has been solved. sorry to bother you sir.

Comment: ignore it sir. i have done it with notification center

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there? one of my friend's have a query. i am posting it here.

Comment: okay sir. doing it

Comment: okay sir doing it